The continuity of $T_p S$ does not guarantee the differentiability of the unit normal vector
I am little bit confused about the differentiability of the unit normal vector $N$.
Show that if all the normal lines to a surface pass through a fixed point, then the surface is (a portion of) a sphere.
In this question, they are using $\frac{\partial N}{\partial u}$, which MUST assume $N$ is differentiable at $(u,v)$.
But I am really doughtful about this assumption since the surface $S$ is NOT given as a regular surface, but only guarantees the continuity.
More precisely, I am considering two counterexamples.

Non-orientable surface

Some surfaces with parametrization being of class $C^1$ - only differentiable once.


For second one, say the surface is $z= \left( x^2 + y^2 \right)^{\frac{4}{3}}$.
It is clear that the surface has continuous $T_p S$ as it admits $xy$-plane as a tangent plane at the origin.
But $z_{xx}$ does not exist at the origin, which can interrupt the differentiability of $N= \dfrac{ \mathbf{x}_u \land \mathbf{x}_v} {\vert \mathbf{x}_u \land \mathbf{x}_v \vert}$.
Is my observation true? Or is there any way to say $N$ is differentiable for any surfaces with continuous $T_p S$?

Most elementary differential geometry books — for example, mine, from which this question may have been taken — define a surface to be a ($C^2$ or $C^3$) regularly parametrized surface in some neighborhood of every point. (My book is freely available at the link in my profile.)  Context is often not provided in questions on this site.

@TedShifrin No, we cannot say the surface is regularly parametrized in this book (it's do Carmo). The second example is exactly the one given by the book.

Sloppily written question, then. You will find such things happen in textbooks.
